How do i solve the code pipeline service permission issue
I am performing cross account deployment and I have created pipeline in the tools account and when i run the pipeline I am getting error as "The service role or action role doesn’t have the permissions required to access the Amazon S3 bucket named privacy-event-processor-pipeline-km-artifactbucket-ejnoeedwqgck. Update the IAM role permissions, and then try again. Error: Amazon S3:AccessDenied:Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: FQ3BP5KY9KDJZ5DX; S3 Extended Request ID: d0Dms19/xoPJBPMwzPPfB0mNXjfYG4CoFZaqN2IvOFt2wivLPj7zNfGx5wosuQMdJ0Q0vxB58Oc=; Proxy: null)".
I tried modifying the IAM permission but still no luck. Below is the policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "codepipeline:CreatePipeline",
                "codepipeline:GetPipeline",
                "codepipeline:UpdatePipeline",
                "codepipeline:DeletePipeline",
                "codepipeline:StartPipelineExecution",
                "codepipeline:StopPipelineExecution",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResources",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:ListStacks",
                "codecommit:ListRepositories",
                "codecommit:GetBranch",
                "codecommit:GetRepository",
                "codecommit:ListBranches",
                "codecommit:GetCommit",
                "codecommit:GetRepositoryTriggers",
                "codecommit:GitPull",
                "codecommit:UploadArchive",
                "codecommit:CancelUploadArchive",
                "codebuild:BatchGetBuilds",
                "codebuild:StartBuild",
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DeleteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:SetStackPolicy",
                "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "codepipeline:StartPipelineExecution"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::privacy-event-processor-pipeline-km-artifactbucket-ejnoeedwqgck",
                "arn:aws:s3:::privacy-event-processor-pipeline-km-artifactbucket-ejnoeedwqgck/*",
                "arn:aws:codecommit:us-west-2:009988776655:privacy-events-processor",
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:112233445566:stack/privacy-events-processor-pipeline/fbd3d390-938d-11ef-9870-0a41f2f17491/*",
                "arn:aws:codepipeline:us-west-2:112233445566:privacy-events-processor"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:112233445566:key/a087e598-256a-4c33-893d-315da1a9ee3a",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::privacy-event-processor-pipeline-km-artifactbucket-ejnoeedwqgck/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::privacy-event-processor-pipeline-km-artifactbucket-ejnoeedwqgck"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::009988776655:role/PrivacEventProcessorPipelineCodeCommitRole",
                "arn:aws:iam::009988776655:role/PrivacEventProcessorPipelineCloudFormationRole",
                "arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/PrivacEventProcessorPipelineCloudFormationRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}


Updating the IAM policy to have access to a different account's bucket is not enough. If it was, then anyone that knew your AWS account ID could give themselves access to your AWS resources. The account that owns the bucket also has to give the other account access to the bucket, via a bucket policy. There is an example of doing that documented here.

my cross account setup is there are 2 account sandbox and tools account and I have deployed the pipeline in tools account and my s3 bucket is in tolls to store the artifacts. Now when I run the pipeline in my tools account then I am getting the above error and the policy mentioned is the policy of my pipeline
